# Extract json values in sql query

Tags: sql, json

Here is an SQL query and its result. How can I make it display only the names of the aircraft in English?

```
select model from aircrafts_data where range < 5000
```

Output:

[image]

I think this can be solved somehow through json conversion, but I don’t know how.

Comment: Kindly paste the code here instead of posting an image hosted somewhere else

Comment: MySQL and Postgresql and different kinds of database that have completely different approaches to json. We need to know which one you actually have.

Answer (score 2):

For `postgresql`, you could use the `->>` operator to get the value associated with a key in a JSON object.

For example,

```
SELECT model->>'en' as model_en
FROM aircrafts_data
WHERE range < 5000;
```

And as @ysth mentioned in the comment
In `mysql`

```
SELECT model->>'$.en' as model_en
FROM aircrafts_data
WHERE range < 5000;
```

Comment: in mysql, `SELECT model->>'$.en'`